# Get specific int in hashset

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to get specific items selected in an alert dialog box to show in a different class and also take corresponding values to add as a price. I want it to show what is selected. I know the for loop is wrong; what should go there so I have the array at the position value of the hashset.

```
final String[] OptionsStringARR = {"Babysit", "Snorkelling", "Test1", "Test2"};
final int[] OptionsPricingARR = {10, 35, 14, 9};
final ArrayList OptionssSelected = new ArrayList();
final HashSet<Integer> optset = new HashSet<>();
boolean[] checked= {false,false,false,false};
public class OptionClass implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ibMap.this)
                .setTitle(guidedetail.getText() + " available options.")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(OptionsStringARR, checked,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId,
                                                boolean isSelected) {
                                if (isSelected) {
                                    checked[selectedItemId]=true;
                                    optset.add(selectedItemId);

                                } else if (optset.contains(selectedItemId)) {
                                    checked[selectedItemId]=false;
                                    optset.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedItemId));

                                }
                            }

                        })
                        //.setMessage("//I need to put shit here. Array lists maybe. and check boxes")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        }

                )
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                //optset.addAll(OptionssSelected);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }

                ).create().show();
    }

}
```

I'm using 2 arrays and a hashset to define what they are, the hashset to determine what is selected, and then arrays that contain the information.

```
public class ConfirmClass implements View.OnClickListener {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int TotalOpt=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < optset.size(); j++){
            int[] y = new int[optset.size()];

            int x = y[j];
            TotalOpt=TotalOpt+ OptionsPricingARR[x];
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < optset.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(OptionsStringARR[i]);
        }
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ibMap.this)
                .setTitle(guidedetail.getText())
                .setMessage("Options Selected: " + sb +
                        "\nTotal: "+ TotalOpt)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        }

                )
                .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(ibMap.this, confirm.class));
                            }
                        }

                ).create().show();
    }

}
```

Thanks! Also if you could help show the price of options via alertdialog that would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted a *lot* of code, but very little of it seems to have anything to do with "get specific int in hashset" and your description is unclear. Please reduce your code to a minimal example of what you're trying to achieve, ideally as a [mcve]. Unless your problem is specific to Android or specific to a user interface element, I'd try to demonstrate it in a console app that we can just copy/paste/compile/run.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a separate class for `Option`, like one shown below:

```
class Option {
  private Integer itemId;
  private String stringARR;
  private Integer pricingARR;

  public Option(Integer itemId, String stringARR, Integer pricingARR) {
    // constructor code
  }

  // setter and getters
}
```

Use a pre-populated `Map<Integer, Option>` instead of using 2 arrays for option string and pricing, like:

```
final static Map<Integer, Option> optionMap = new HashMap<>();
final Set<Integer> optset = new HashSet<>();

// pre initialize options in map for later use
static{
    optionMap.put(1, new Option(1, "Babysit", 10));     // assuming 1 is option id for "Babysit"
    optionMap.put(2, new Option(2, "Snorkelling", 35)); // assuming 2 is option id for "Snorkelling"
    // populate other options
}
```

Then in your method `onClick` of class `ConfirmClass`, use below code for pricing and string concatenation:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int totalOpt=0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = optset.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            // add option price
            totalOpt += optionMap.get(iterator.next()).getPricingARR();

            // append option description
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(optionMap.get(iterator.next()).getStringARR());
        }

        // rest of the code
    }
```

*Note:* Looking at your code, I have assumed that options in your application are fixed, that is why I have used `static` initializer block..